# Retrieving data from PostgreSQL using pg_trgm is too slow

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-ec2

I'm developing Django app.
This app retrieves data from postgresql by pg_trgm to make it faster.

In local environment, it works well and fast, but ec2 environment, it takes a long time to get data and display on the result page.

below are the performance of the two environments.
With "explain (ANALYZE true, BUFFERS true)"

Local PC

> explain (ANALYZE true, BUFFERS true) select * from test_eu where eng_discription ~ '.*remote controller.*' ORDER BY image_amount DESC;

```
 Sort  (cost=283.37..283.52 rows=58 width=1413) (actual time=24160.281..24160.284 rows=39 loops=1)
   Sort Key: image_amount DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 90kB
   Buffers: shared hit=281 read=106692
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_eu  (cost=52.86..281.67 rows=58 width=1413) (actual time=23862.313..24157.424 rows=39 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (eng_discription ~ '.*remote controller.*'::text)
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1198
         Heap Blocks: exact=1151
         Buffers: shared hit=278 read=106692
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on text_index  (cost=0.00..52.84 rows=58 width=0) (actual time=23841.221..23841.221 rows=1237 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (eng_discription ~ '.*remote controller.*'::text)
               Buffers: shared read=105354
 Planning Time: 0.967 ms
 Execution Time: 24175.431 ms
```

ec2

> explain (ANALYZE true, BUFFERS true) select * from test_eu where eng_discription ~ '.*remote controller.*' ORDER BY image_amount DESC;

```
 Sort  (cost=283.27..283.41 rows=58 width=1410) (actual time=24206.981..24207.01
6 rows=39 loops=1)
   Sort Key: image_amount DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 90kB
   Buffers: shared hit=1816 read=104846
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_eu  (cost=52.86..281.57 rows=58 width=1410) (act
ual time=23721.463..24206.823 rows=39 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (eng_discription ~ '.*remote controller.*'::text)
         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1198
         Heap Blocks: exact=1158
         Buffers: shared hit=1813 read=104846
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on text_index  (cost=0.00..52.84 rows=58 width=0)
 (actual time=23701.589..23701.590 rows=1237 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (eng_discription ~ '.*remote controller.*'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=1530 read=103506
 Planning Time: 15.179 ms
 Execution Time: 24208.865 ms
```

Results are close, so I wonder why ec2 environment is slow.
Please teach me where should I check?

PS.
My local PC's memory is 8GB and ec2 uses instance type of "t2.micro" it means memory is 1GB.Does it related to this problem??

Comment: Yes, lack of memory could be the reason. Please paste the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE TRUE, BUFFERS TRUE) SELECT ...` from both environments.

Comment: We need `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to answer the question.

Comment: I edited code in my post with the results of "EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)"
Thank you.

Comment: Buffer disk reads and execution times are pretty much the same. If you experience the EC2 to be slower then it could be because of the time that it takes the client (in your case Django) to fetch data from the DB. What size is the resulting data set? Is the Django server located near to the DB server?

Comment: dump file's size is 410MB and it has 500,000records
and I think  Django server located near to the DB server.

Do you think just upgrading memory is not the solution for it??
Thank you.

Comment: A PC with decent local disks is often faster than a hosted database.

Comment: Both of the queries you show took a shade over 24 seconds.  Did you paste the wrong plan in there for the allegedly fast one?